# How to write in HAML template javascript loop with data from controller?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, haml

I am getting from controller data in global variable `@controller_data` which contains array.

I am also using Highcharts, where is used following procedure for rendering data in charts:

```
data = [{
           y: 55.11,
           color: colors[0]
         }, {
           y: 21.63,
           color: colors[1]
         }, {
           y: 11.94,
           color: colors[2]
         }, {
           y: 7.15,
           color: colors[3]
         }, {
           y: 2.14,
           color: colors[4]
         }];
```

I am using HAML template system. How to fill out this Javascript array with data from controller?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `@controller_data` is just a simple array of hashes, suitable for passing directly to JavaScript:

```
:javascript
  data = #{@controller_data.to_json};
```

Haml allows you to do string interpolation inside of content, including [JavaScript Filters](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#javascript-filter).

Comment: Thank you @Phrogz, but I would need to prepare exactly the same array as is in the example above, `.to_json` doesn't prepare it that way.

Comment: @user984621 If you want more help, you need to provide the data of your `@controller_data`. For example, what does `@controller_data.inspect` produce?